# React.js random variable in URL GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, reactjs, fetch

I'm using React.js to fetch a list of comments from my Express server but my GET URL keeps getting appended with random variable strings like "?_1441474975073"

```
// Error in Chrome console

GET http://localhost:4000/comments.json?_=1441474975073 404 (Not Found)
/comments.json error Not Found
```

Can someone tell me why??

```
// main.js
React.render(
    <CommentBox url="/comments" />,
    document.getElementById('reactComment')
);

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({comments: data})
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    ...
});

// server.js
app.get('/comments', function(req, res) {
    Comments.find().exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(JSON.parse(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to leave comments yet so I'll just answer here.

You have `cache: false` set so jQuery appends a timestamp so that a fresh copy of the JSON is always called.

This isn't likely the cause of the 404 error, however.